# Phone contact after no response from scientific collaborator?

Tags: email, collaboration

I have a scientific collaboration with a senior scientist from a University in Europe. He agreed to work with me on the project and our roles were defined in the process(only supervision and minimal interaction from his side and active contribution from my side). Emails were received regularly from his side till December 22nd (prior to the holidays). After the holidays (on January 8th) I sent him the work that we agreed upon and he has to verify my conclusions and let me know whether I can proceed forward.  Yesterday I emailed him  inquiring whether his busy schedule has prevented him from responding to my document. Should I assume there is no further interest from his side or can I call him to find out what his thought process is ?

Comment: remind him again.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist - phone or email ?

Comment: I would not send a reminder after 1 day.

Comment: "whether his busy schedule has prevented him from responding to my document" this wording can come across as sarcastic. I'd say something more like "just following up on x" next time.
But the poster above is right. Don't send a reminder after one day. Reach out again, ring him in a week. If he doesn't answer, wait a few days and send an email. Be polite, just say you're following up because you'd like to proceed on the work, blah blah.

Comment: Or call him sooner if it's actually urgent. Just don't send two emails in two days ;)

Comment: Since it is European University, call him to his office phone (most likely shown in the email) and be open about it. People don't like emailing too much here, especially the older generations. Don't be afraid to put him a bit on the spot, but stay polite and start the conversation with "Dear Sir", always works!

Comment: @Cninroh - thanks a lot. I did not know people did not like email in Europe. I will be sure to call a lot of people moving forward